# easy to use framework for using GWT MVP with minimal coding

Tags: gwt, mvp, gwt2

I am looking for a framework/library that generates most/all of the generic MVP code itself, so that I can then extend that code. In default GWT-Eclipse IDE setup, I have to write every bit of code by hand.

I have seen a few frameworks like Tessell which aim at generating a large part of the boiler plate code...Which framework do you recommend for this purpose, so that I can create new MVP-GWT apps with minimal effort/fuss?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Tessell](http://www.tessell.org/):

Tessell is a GWT application framework

- Follows a Model View Presenter architecture
- Less boilerplate (10x less LOC than hand-coded MVP)

**Features**

- View generation of the MVP/UiBinder interfaces/implementations that allow for fast, DOM-decoupled unit tests but that suck to code by hand
- Rich models to make your application's presenter/business logic more declarative and have less spaghetti/inner class code
- Dispatch-style server/client AJAX communication
- Stubs for awesome, out-of-the-box tests
- Conventions for forms, row tables, and cell tables

Answer (score 2):

I know people who have used [mvp4g](http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/) on some large projects effectively.

Answer (score 2):

I used [gwtp](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) in two projects and it worked really well.
It has the concept of nested presenters/views which might come handy if you want to create reusable MVP components.

Answer (score 1):

The GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse) and Google Window Builder together will generate most of what you need for MVP code using the GWT libraries. You go to New ->Window Builder->GWT UIBindder->MVP->MVP View.  The Wizard will generate the uibinder code, a UI interface, a UI implementation, a place, and an activity.  It will also use a client factory if you are using one.  If you have a client.place and/or a client.activity  package(s) it will also put the places and activities in those packages for you.